# Css select empty array from .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am saving an array into a button via Jquery .data().

If the array is empty, I'd like that button to be red.

How can I match the empty-array button via CSS?

```js
var values1 = [];
var values2 = ['not', 'empty'];

$('.button1').data('values', values1);
$('.button2').data('values', values2);
```

```css
button[data-values='[]'] { // THIS IS WRONG
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="values1">Hello1</button>
<button class="values2">Hello2</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery doesn't store data in attributes. It uses external expando object to avoid memory leaks in elder browsers and varios serialization/deserialization issues.

If you want to store data in DOM you need to use `attr` instead. Though I don't think it is great idea. Consider rethinking your approach to styling (for example you could add some semantic class instead)

```js
var values1 = [];
var values2 = ['not', 'empty'];

$('.values1').attr('data-values', JSON.stringify(values1));
$('.values2').attr('data-values', JSON.stringify(values2));
```

```css
button[data-values='[]'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="values1">Hello1</button>
<button class="values2">Hello2</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some mistakes, firstly your javascript is trying to change the buttons with class `button1` and `button2` but your buttons have the class `values1` and `values2`.

Also to add an attribute, I always use the `.attr()` function from jQuery because I have also had the issue of attributes not being added when using the `.data()` to add. So I use `.data()` only to retrieve the data attributes.

You should also `strigify` your arrays before putting them in the HTML attribute.

```js
var values1 = [];
var values2 = ['not', 'empty'];

$('.button1').attr('data-values',JSON.stringify(values1));
$('.button2').attr('data-values', JSON.stringify(values2));
```

```css
button[data-values='[]'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1">Hello1</button>
<button class="button2">Hello2</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for empty array just put the if condition check out the example below. I hope this will help you

```
.btnEmpty{
        color: red;
    }



    if (values1.length === 0) {
            $('button').addClass('btnEmpty');
        }else{
            $('button').removeClass('btnEmpty');
        }
```

and if you want to check both `var` then just `||` in if condition

```
if (values1.length === 0 || values2.length === 0) {
        $('button').addClass('btnEmpty');
    }else{
        $('button').removeClass('btnEmpty');
    }
```